# FOR IF Loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple question. I want to make an if statement in this code (**if(i=2){str += 'test';}**):

```
    var data = response.DATA;
    var str = '<ul>';
    for (var I = 0; I < data.length; I++) {
        str += '<li><a href="#blog?blog_id=' +  data[I][0] + '"data-transition="slide">' +      data[I][1] + '</a></li>';
 if(I=2){str += 'test';}
        }
    str += '</ul>';
    $('#output').html(str);
}
```

When I do, it's placing the word 'test' not only at row 2, but on every row.

Comment: `if(I==2)` or `if(I===2)`, `I=2` is assigning 2 to I...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `==` or `===` to compare two values :

```
  if (I===2) {str += 'test';}
```

The result of `I=2`, which changes the value of `I`, is `2`, which evaluates as true in an `if`.

Comment: better use this === for also beeing sure the type is correct ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your script:

```
if (I=2) ...
```

means that `I` is always 2 because you're assigning 2 to it.